# game center score submitting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have this turn based game and my game center is working, leader board working only the point submitting is not going how it should. In my game I have a `UILabel` to display my score and every time you play a game it gets the score that is your previous highscore so you can make that even higher, I use this code:

```
if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) 
{
    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID, nil];
    GKLeaderboard *board = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] initWithPlayerIDs:arr];

    if(board != nil)
    {
        board.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        board.range = NSMakeRange(1, 1);
        board.category = @"750";
        [board loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {

            if (error != nil)
            {
                // handle the error.
                NSLog(@"Error retrieving score.", nil);
            }
            if (scores != nil)
            {
                NSString *scrVal = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", ((GKScore*)[scores objectAtIndex:0]).value + 1];
                //score += 2500;
                //NSString *scrVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
                lblScore.text = scrVal;

                GKScore *myScoreValue = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"750"] autorelease];
                myScoreValue.value = scrVal;

                [myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

                    if(error != nil)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Score Submission Failed");
                    }
                    else {
                        NSLog(@"Score Submitted");
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    }
    [board release];
    [arr release];
}
```

I just tried and it does submits a score but not the correct one,As you can see in my code I want it to go to 1 score point higher. the previous score was 2120 and it displayed that but when I put in the correct word and this code was running it made my new leader board score 287,343,904 so thats like another 280 million words later but I just did one.

Hope someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From GKScore class reference:

```
value
The score earned by the player.

@property(nonatomic, assign) int64_t value
```

value is an int, but you are setting a string pointer to it.